# Is Google / Are Searchengines compiler?

Tags: search, search-engine, theory, google-search

I was wondering whether search engines / searches / google could be treated as compiler?

When I enter a search term to google, they analyze the term for certain patterns e.g. `from a to b` or so. And if you would leave out all the optimizations and assume that they would need to come up with the results from scratch for every term I enter.

When they analyze the input they need to do things (at least partly) similar to what a compiler does. Just more or less language independent. Doing a lexical, syntax and schematic analysis and ultimately transforming this into SQL or similar. And for certain patterns they want to come up with the same results just like a compiler. Also even native language does follow somewhat kind of hierarchy.

Could I than say that it is (at least in theory) like a compiler? Is it more an Interpreter kind of thing? Or rather something completely independent?

Comment: more like query engine that includes compiler and tons of other things (like optimizer and planner)

Comment: so it is even more than "just" a compiler?

Comment: yep, compiling is just a pre-requisite step